# API not returning all expected values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, controller, .net-core

I re-edited this question.

I have an API method that should return a single customer including data from other tables. When I test the API with Swagger I get values for some IDs but not for customerId == 1.

The DAL customer model class:

```
public class Customer : AuditableEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other props deleted for readability 

    public ICollection<Shipping> Shippings {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Billing> Billings {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Payer> Payers {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Logistic> Logistics {get; set; }

}
```

The Shipping model class

```
public class Shipping : AuditableEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other props deleted for readability

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

The CustomerViewModel

```
 public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other props deleted for readability

    public ICollection<ShippingViewModel> Shippings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BillingViewModel> Billings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PayerViewModel> Payers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LogisticViewModel> Logistics { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerViewModel>
{
    public CustomerViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(register => register.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Customer name cannot be empty");
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    public Customer GetCustomerById(int customerId)
    {
        return _appContext.Customers
            .Include(c => c.Shippings)
            .Include(c => c.Billings)
            .Include(c => c.Payers)
            .Include(c => c.Logistics)
            .Single(x => x.Id == customerId) 
            //.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == customerId)               
            ;
    }
```

The API controller

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    readonly ILogger _logger;
    readonly IEmailer _emailer;


    public CustomerController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<CustomerController> logger, IEmailer emailer,
            IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailer = emailer;
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    // GET api/value/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetCustomerById(int id)
    {
        var customer = _unitOfWork.Customers.GetCustomerById(id);
        return Ok(Mapper.Map<Customer>(customer));
    }
```

Database has values 1 to 6 for table customer.
The table shippings contains 1 value linked to the customerId == 1.

When I test the API I cannot get the values for customerId == 1. It result in a response code 0. Header == "error": "no response from server". And the response body = "no content".

When I test it with ID == 2, 3, ... I can get values ex:
response code == 200
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Inion",
  // rest removed for readability
  "shippings": [],
  "billings": [],
  "payers": [],
  "logistics": [],
  "updatedDate": "2018-02-08T15:41:45.4929139",
  "createdDate": "2018-02-08T15:41:45.4929139"
  }

Comment: I don't see any `OrderBy`, so the question doesn't make any sense because database tables have no inherent order.

Comment: `Single` throws an exception if there are two results, so your question makes no sense

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Should be find if that id is the primary key.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: When the OP says the first is not returned but the others are they are not talking about in a single results set. They mean that when querying for id=1 then no document is returned but when querying for id=2 and so on then the document is returned as expected. So the OP is asking why is nothing returned when id=1 whereas it is when id>1. Each query should only ever return a single result though as I understand it so ordering is not relevant.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear in the question, I've edited the question. @Chris is right. I can get the values for id 2,3,... but not for id 1 with the include(). There's no need for an order as only 1 item should be returned, and it does that for id 2,3...

Comment: If the `Includes` work for id 2, but not 1 I'd look to see what the difference is between them.  What are the foreign key values for those navigation properties?  Also profile the SQL that's generated.  Finally `Single` should either return a value or throw, so did you catch and exception by any chance?  Maybe show the code that handles the requests and calls your methods?

Comment: What if there is a problem with the data and the navigation fails for your id = 1? Maybe something is missing from another table for that join. You should try to replicate the LINQ with sql directly with all the joins.

Comment: Can you please remove so many screenshots so it's easier to read the question? It's hard to understand as is. But as juharr mentions, I'd use SQL Profiler (if using SQL Server). Also, your title still doesn't make sense as the error it states is not what this question represents

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto done. I'll check the db as you all commented

Comment: You're showing your data access code while the problem is with the code calling this. Show your API controller.

Comment: Do you have Id=1 in any of Shippings, Billings, Payers, Logistics?

Comment: My crystal ball says that Single() applied to the previous Include() instead of the entire query.  Using () parentheses ought to fix that.

Comment: thanks again for the quick respones and thank@CodeCaster to point to the api controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who responded quickly and sorry if I wasn't clear.

After having checked the db I couldn't find something wrong.

@CodeCaster pointed to the API controller and overlooked that I mapped the wrong class.

Off course I had return values for other IDs with empty tags as the other IDs hadn't values linked in the other tables, only id=1 had. I've tested it again with the change and added more data in the linked tables to be sure and all is working as expected.

The correct API controller method

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetCustomerById(int id)
    {
        var customer = _unitOfWork.Customers.GetCustomerById(id);
        return Ok(Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(customer));
    }
```